# Application bar icons name

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, application-bar

How could I make the application bar setting or any other changes so that the names below the application bar icon are displayed by default when the page is loaded without any user interaction. Like in the this [Image](http://3mspaints.co.uk/img/A-Bar.png), but in the image at that link user had to click on the application bar dots in order to show the names below the icons. I know its possible because I had seen in some application on my phone.

Comment: Microsoft decided that WP7 apps should always show a clean, *minimal*, set of options by default. If you go against their app-bar standard it may not pass approval (assuming your target is the marketplace). You can always create your own application bar control if you really must do that.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this with the current version (7.1.1) of the SDK. The `ApplicationBar`'s `Mode` property only has two states; `ApplicationBarMode.Default` (ie. Normal state, displays any icons, but not their text, and the ellipsis to see menu items) and `ApplicationBarMode.Minimized` which shows only the ellipsis, and no icons, until expansion. See [ApplicationBar.Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar.mode%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for more information.